# why it always give zero output?

Tags: c++, io

```
int i;
cin>>i;
cout<<i
```

when we entered Character i.e 'A' why it gives Zero output ?

Answer (score 7):

Because `A` is not a numeric value suitable for storing in an integer, so it will leave your integer alone, as shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    int i = 12345;
    std::cin >> i;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When you run that code and enter `A`, it outputs `12345` as the value doesn't change.

If you want truly robust input, it's usually better to input lines as strings then convert them yourself.

"Mickey-mouse" programs or those where you have total control over the input can use the sort of input methods you're using, serious code should use more suitable methods.

---

If your intent is to convert an input character into its integer code, you can use something like:

```
#include <iostream>
int main (void) {
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    std::cout << (int)c << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should always check if the operation succeeded before continuing.

```
int i;
if (cin >> i)
    cout << i;
else
    cout << "Not a valid number!";
```

Answer (score 0):

because the value 'A' is not stored in the variable i since it is a integer variable. i believe that is the reason the initial value 12345 is printed on the screen...